# attempt to hack our website - URLdecode

Tags: mysql, database, xss

Is there anyone who knows how to decode the following URL. Which I guess was an automated attempt to hack into our database:

http://www.our-webiste.com/web/gallery_album?albumid=999999.9%20union%20all%20select%200x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536--

Comment: Pick a programming language. Find its URL decoding library function and use that.

Comment: Our website uses PHP but I cant decode it with urldecode. Anyone knows an online-decoder for this kind of string?

Comment: 0x31303235343830303536 == ?1025480056 ...  The Havij SQL injection tool appears to be a common source of these attacks that select 0x31303235343830303536 as a placeholder column, perhaps they'd be willing to shed some light on the specific mechanism in action there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SQL injection attack:

1. albumid=999999.9 (End of your current query)
2. `%20` is just a space
3. `union all select` (Join to new query)
4. `0x31303235343830303536` (NULL. They are matching the number of columns in your existing query. If you had `SELECT * FROM albums` and `albums` had 3 columns, them the `UNION` must also be 3 columns)
5. `%2C` is a comma
6. 0x31303235343830303536 (NULL again)
7. And so on and so forth...